# Como formatar um Label usando StringFormat no Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, wpf, xamarin-forms, xaml

Estou criando uma solução onde devo exibir um inteiro em uma `<Label />`. Para fazer isso estou usando o código abaixo:

```
public partial class Home : ContentPage {

    public Home() {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Mockup();
    }

    private int Foo { get; set; }

    private void Mockup() {
        Foo = 10;
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="Test.Home">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <Label Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=TwoWay } />
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Preciso que meu texto sempre esteja com uma máscara de 8 dígitos. Como devo aplicar a máscara à propriedade `StringFormat` para que o valor exibido seja `00000010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="Test.Home">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <Label Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0,8:00000000}'}" />
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```